# Android Espresso: How to check that Toast message is NOT shown?

Tags: android, testing, functional-testing, android-espresso

I'm working now in my functional tests and in one of them I have to test that a toast message is NOT shown. Considering this is the code I'm using to check if the toast message is shown (this code works):

```
onView(withText(R.string.my_toast_message))
        .inRoot(withDecorView(not(getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView())))
        .check(matches(isDisplayed()));
```

below you can find the code I'm using to check that a toast message is NOT shown (none of them work):

Approach one:

```
onView(withText(R.string.error_invalid_login))
        .inRoot(withDecorView(not(getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView())))
        .check(matches(not(isDisplayed())));
```

Approach two:

```
onView(withText(R.string.error_invalid_login))
        .inRoot(withDecorView(not(getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView())))
        .check(doesNotExist());
```

Any idea about how can I check that a toast message is not shown would be really appreciated :)

Comment: Your second approach seems to be correct to me. What kind of unexpected behavior are you getting if you're saying it's not working?

Comment: The second approach is working for me. As @appoll said, what is the result of running the second approach in a test?

Comment: I get a NoMatchingRootException for your approach two, so its not really working for me either, did you get it to work?

Answer (score 7):

The best way to test toast message in espresso is using a custom matcher:

```
public class ToastMatcher extends TypeSafeMatcher<Root> {
    @Override public void describeTo(Description description) {
        description.appendText("is toast");
    }

    @Override public boolean matchesSafely(Root root) {
        int type = root.getWindowLayoutParams().get().type;
        if ((type == WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_TOAST)) {
            IBinder windowToken = root.getDecorView().getWindowToken();
            IBinder appToken = root.getDecorView().getApplicationWindowToken();
            if (windowToken == appToken) {
                //means this window isn't contained by any other windows. 
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

This you can use in your test case:

1. Test if the Toast Message is Displayed

   ```
   onView(withText(R.string.message)).inRoot(new ToastMatcher())
   .check(matches(isDisplayed()));
   ```
2. Test if the Toast Message is not Displayed

   ```
   onView(withText(R.string.message)).inRoot(new ToastMatcher())
   .check(matches(not(isDisplayed())));
   ```
3. Test id the Toast contains specific Text Message

   ```
   onView(withText(R.string.message)).inRoot(new ToastMatcher())
   .check(matches(withText("Invalid Name"));
   ```

I copied this answer from my blog -
http://qaautomated.blogspot.in/2016/01/how-to-test-toast-message-using-espresso.html

Comment: What do you do if you don't have an ID for the Toast? i.e. Say you don't have R.string.message?

Comment: You can add the complete text as per displayed in the toast message.

Comment: that's not a good option since throwing and catching `NoMatchingRootException` consumes a lot of time in a comparison with the default test case. Seems that Espresso is waiting for the Root for a while

Comment: theres no return true in this example?

Answer (score 6):

It is required to catch the case when the toast does not exist, for which a `NoMatchingRootException` is thrown. Below shows the "Espresso way" of catching that.

```
public static Matcher<Root> isToast() {
    return new WindowManagerLayoutParamTypeMatcher("is toast", WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_TOAST);
}
public static void assertNoToastIsDisplayed() {
    onView(isRoot())
            .inRoot(isToast())
            .withFailureHandler(new PassMissingRoot())
            .check(matches(not(anything("toast root existed"))))
    ;
}
```

A quick (self-)test that uses the above:

```
@Test public void testToastMessage() {
    Toast toast = createToast("Hello Toast!");
    assertNoToastIsDisplayed();
    toast.show();
    onView(withId(android.R.id.message))
            .inRoot(isToast())
            .check(matches(withText(containsStringIgnoringCase("hello"))));
    toast.cancel();
    assertNoToastIsDisplayed();
}

private Toast createToast(final String message) {
    final AtomicReference<Toast> toast = new AtomicReference<>();
    InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().runOnMainSync(new Runnable() {
        @SuppressLint("ShowToast") // will be shown later
        @Override public void run() {
            toast.set(Toast.makeText(InstrumentationRegistry.getContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG));
        }
    });
    return toast.get();
}
```

The magical reusable helper classes:

```
public class PassMissingRoot implements FailureHandler {
    private final FailureHandler defaultHandler
            = new DefaultFailureHandler(InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext());
    @Override public void handle(Throwable error, Matcher<View> viewMatcher) {
        if (!(error instanceof NoMatchingRootException)) {
            defaultHandler.handle(error, viewMatcher);
        }
    }
}

public class WindowManagerLayoutParamTypeMatcher extends TypeSafeMatcher<Root> {
    private final String description;
    private final int type;
    private final boolean expectedWindowTokenMatch;
    public WindowManagerLayoutParamTypeMatcher(String description, int type) {
        this(description, type, true);
    }
    public WindowManagerLayoutParamTypeMatcher(String description, int type, boolean expectedWindowTokenMatch) {
        this.description = description;
        this.type = type;
        this.expectedWindowTokenMatch = expectedWindowTokenMatch;
    }
    @Override public void describeTo(Description description) {
        description.appendText(this.description);
    }
    @Override public boolean matchesSafely(Root root) {
        if (type == root.getWindowLayoutParams().get().type) {
            IBinder windowToken = root.getDecorView().getWindowToken();
            IBinder appToken = root.getDecorView().getApplicationWindowToken();
            if (windowToken == appToken == expectedWindowTokenMatch) {
                // windowToken == appToken means this window isn't contained by any other windows.
                // if it was a window for an activity, it would have TYPE_BASE_APPLICATION.
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can easily add a timeout by adding `if (timeout[0]) throw new RuntimeException("Searched for root until timeout");`at the beginning of `matchesSafely`. Then set `timeout[0]=true` from outside after a few seconds. If you use a custom exception instead, you can catch it in the test case.

Comment: is this work on android 11 / 12?

Answer (score 3):

Seems that such simple check is impossible with espresso if you have not only toast but a `PopupWindow`, for example.

For this case is suggest just to give up with espresso here and use `UiAutomator` for this assertion

```
val device: UiDevice
   get() = UiDevice.getInstance(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation())

fun assertPopupIsNotDisplayed() {
    device.waitForIdle()
    assertFalse(device.hasObject(By.text(yourText))))
}

fun assertPopupIsDisplayed() {
    device.waitForIdle()
    assertTrue(device.hasObject(By.text(yourText))))
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This works

```
boolean exceptionCaptured = false;
try {
  onView(withText(R.string.error_invalid_login))
          .inRoot(withDecorView(not(is(getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView()))))
          .check(doesNotExist());
}catch (NoMatchingRootException e){
  exceptionCaptured = true;
}finally {
  assertTrue(exceptionCaptured);
}
```

Comment: as a side note this code can do both exist and does not exist. All we need to do to set boolean flags correctly. Great answer.

Comment: that's not a good option since throwing and catching NoMatchingRootException consumes a lot of time in a comparison with the default test case. Seems that Espresso is waiting for the Root for a while

Answer (score 1):

#### In Kotlin you can test Toast by custom class like this

```
import android.os.IBinder
import android.view.WindowManager
import androidx.test.espresso.Root
import org.hamcrest.Description
import org.hamcrest.TypeSafeMatcher

class ToastMatcher : TypeSafeMatcher<Root?>() {

    override fun matchesSafely(item: Root?): Boolean {
        val type: Int? = item?.windowLayoutParams?.get()?.type
        if (type == WindowManager.LayoutParams.FIRST_APPLICATION_WINDOW) {
            val windowToken: IBinder = item.decorView.windowToken
            val appToken: IBinder = item.decorView.applicationWindowToken
            if (windowToken === appToken) { // means this window isn't contained by any other windows.
                return true
            }
        }
        return false
    }

    override fun describeTo(description: Description?) {
        description?.appendText("is toast")
    }
}
```

##### Use it in your test function like this:

```
onView(withText("Your toast text"))
    .inRoot(ToastMatcher().apply {
        matches(isDisplayed())
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

I know its late but may be this will help somebody else.

```
    onView(withText("Test")).inRoot(withDecorView(not(mActivityRule.getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView())))
            .check(doesNotExist());
```

Answer (score 0):

Like @anuja jain's answer but if you get the `NoMatchingRootException` you can comment out the `if ((type == WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_TOAST))` check and add the `return true;` line to the inner if block.

Answer (score -1):

Try with below solution

```
onView(withId(android.R.id.message))
                .inRoot(withDecorView(not(is(mRule.getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView()))))
                .check(matches(withText("Some message")));
```

Answer (score -2):

You can look at the source code [here](https://code.google.com/p/android-test-kit/source/browse/espresso/lib/src/main/java/com/google/android/apps/common/testing/ui/espresso/matcher/ViewMatchers.java) and create your own view matcher that does exactly the opposite.

Comment: 1. link only (already broken), 2. not an answer, the question is not about the opposite, 3. working with non-existent views/roots is not trivial