# espresso how do you check if a dialog isn't visible

Tags: android, kotlin, android-espresso

I have a test that checks to see if a dialog is present or not.

```
@Test
fun dismissedWhenClicked() {
    //dimiss dialog
    onView(withText(R.string.simple)).inRoot(isDialog()).perform(click())
    //check dialog
    onView(isRoot()).inRoot(isDialog()).check(matches(not(isDisplayed())))
}
```

above is my best guess, but fails because `Matcher 'is dialog' did not match any of the following roots`

i have found 3 questions on here that address it but none seem to solve it.

[Espresso check if no dialog is displayed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48960164/espresso-check-if-no-dialog-is-displayed) - the comment works but it also passes when there is a dialog

[Check the dialog is visible - Espresso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53351111/check-the-dialog-is-visible-espresso) - this doesn't check, instead it will just fail gracefully, i think.

[espresso: Assert a Dialog is not shown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39831988/espresso-assert-a-dialog-is-not-shown) - seems to have no answer.

Comment: see also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73894325/191761 a bit of a horrible solution I used, but couldn't find any alternative

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this with a custom matcher [modified slightly from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35077824/1807486)

```
@Test
    fun dismissedWhenClicked() {
        onView(withText(R.string.simple)).inRoot(isDialog()).perform(click())
        onView(withId(R.id.fragment_layout)).inRoot(Utils.ActivityMatcher()).check(matches(isDisplayed()))
    }
```

```
class ActivityMatcher : TypeSafeMatcher<Root>() {
        override fun describeTo(description: Description) {
            description.appendText("is activity")
        }

        public override fun matchesSafely(root: Root): Boolean {
            val type: Int = root.windowLayoutParams.get().type
            if (type == WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_BASE_APPLICATION) {
                val windowToken: IBinder = root.decorView.windowToken
                val appToken: IBinder = root.decorView.applicationWindowToken
                if (windowToken === appToken) {
                    //means this window isn't contained by any other windows.
                    return true
                }
            }
            return false
        }
    }
```